# Rails validates_with error: :attributes cannot be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a `validates_with` validation to some code that makes sure two flags aren't both simultaneously true:

```
validates_with ConfirmationValidator

class ConfirmationValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.confirmed_good && record.confirmed_bad
      record.errors[:base] << "Record is both confirmed and confirmed_bad"
    end
  end
end
```

But attempting to use this gets the following error:

```
gems/activemodel-3.0.7/lib/active_model/validator.rb:142:in `initialize': :attributes cannot be blank (RuntimeError)
```

Looking through that file makes it seem like this is due to some problem passing options, but I still can't quite tell what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the rest of your model code.  The error on line 142 relates to an EachValidator.  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb

Comment: Just a design comment here - confirmed could just be a boolean that's true or false and the problem goes away

Or confirmed_bad could just be a method that returns !confirmed_good?

Answer (score 6):

As @Gazler points out above, your error actually maps to an EachValiator initialization problem. I ran into the same problem.

I'm running rails 3.0.9, using ActiveModel 3.0.9, not quite the same stack you seem to be running. I'm just beginning with custom validators. I have a ActiveModel::EachValidator, not quite what your code sample says. The EachValidator needs attributes passed as an array within the options to validates_with, e.g.

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with GenericValidator, :attributes=>[:name, :image]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you name your validator the same name a Rails validator has been named. Example, naming you validator:

`PresenceValidator` will lead to this exception.